# How can I properly install Win32::GuiTest?

Tags: perl, winapi

I am trying to use [Win32::GuiTest](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::GuiTest) and with Windows XP and `perl` version 5.8.6.

I am getting the following error:

```
Can't locate loadable object for module Win32::GuiTest in @INC (@INC contains: 
C:/Perl/lib C:/Perl/site/lib .) at E:\a\simply.pl line 259
  Compilation failed in require at E:\a\simply.pl line 259.
  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at E:\a\simply.pl line 259
```

I tried following the instructions for [Win32-GuiTest-1.3](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-GuiTest-1.3/). I tried to install:

I created `C:\TEMP` and I downloaded the zip file and extracted  the contents and placed in `C:\TEMP` and gave the command

```
C:\TEMP>ppm
ppm> install C:\temp\win32-guitest.ppd
```

It is giving an error as...

```
Error: no suitable installation target found for package Win32-GuiTest.
```

If I use the package `Win32-GuiTest-1.56`, it is giving the error

```
Error: Package 'win32-guitest' not found. Please 'search' for it first.
```

and if i use the command

```
C:\temp>ppm
ppm> install Win32::GuiTest
```

i get the error as...

```
Error: No valid repositories:
Error: 501 Protocol scheme '' is not supported
Error: 501 Protocol scheme '' is not supported
```

i downloaded from 
**http://search.cpan.org/~erngui/Win32-GuiTest-1.3/GuiTest.pm** for package `Win32-GuiTest-1.3`
and 
**http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-GuiTest/lib/Win32/GuiTest.pm** for package `Win32-GuiTest-1.56`

Comment: Those two files which you downloaded cannot be used to install using `ppm`. They are simple source files, not installation packages. For offline installation with `ppm`, you need `ppd` files. Fix your ppm configuration by adding the requisite repositories.

Comment: Can you tel me how please am newbie and i dono how to install the packages please do the needful

Comment: Which exact version of ActivePerl do you use?

Comment: i am using perl version 5.8.6

Comment: lokesh: Can you install new version of Perl? It seems that your install is not correct. And ppm became much better in fresh version. You will also get benefit of using 5.10 features.

Comment: @Alexandr Ciornii: I would not recommend that the OP re-install AS Perl unless adding the repositories fails (here is a list of repos: http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=PPM_Repositories#Perl_5.8 ). There is a link to the ppm manual in my answer which shows how to add repositories.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Given that you get `Error: No valid repositories`, clearly you have somehow borked your `ppm` configuration. **[Add](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.8/bin/ppm.html) some [repositories](http://trouchelle.com/perl/ppmrepview.pl).**

#### Original answer:

Use `ppm` to install the module:

```
ppm install Win32::GuiTest
```

```
C:\Home> ppm install Win32::GuiTest
Downloading ActiveState Package Repository packlist...done
Updating ActiveState Package Repository database...done
Downloading bribes packlist...done
Updating bribes database...done
Downloading trouchelle packlist...done
Updating trouchelle database...done
Downloading uwinnipeg packlist...not modified
Downloading wxperl packlist...done
Updating wxperl database...done
Downloading Win32-GuiTest-1.54...done
Unpacking Win32-GuiTest-1.54...done
Generating HTML for Win32-GuiTest-1.54...done
Updating files in site area...done
  15 files installed
```

If you want to download the latest and the greatest:

```
C:\Temp> wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/K/KA/KARASIK/Win32-GuiTest-1.56.tar.gz
C:\Temp> tar -xzvf Win32-GuiTest-1.56.tar.gz
C:\Temp> cd Win32-GuiTest-1.56
C:\Temp\Win32-GuiTest-1.56> perl Makefile.PL
Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Win32::GuiTest
C:\Temp\Win32-GuiTest-1.56> dmake
C:\Temp\Win32-GuiTest-1.56> dmake test
C:\Temp\Win32-GuiTest-1.56> dmake install
```

You need to install [mingw](http://blogs.activestate.com/2009/01/ppm-install-mingw/) for this to work.

Comment: I do not know where that `ppd` file came from. Tell us where you got the file (and specify versions) and why you are using this method instead of **`ppm install Win32::GuiTest`**. I also do not know why you are trying nine year old versions of the module.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Active perl installed in your system, open perl package manager. Click on view menu and then click on all packages. In the search box enter win gui. It will list WIN GUI package in grey (not installed ). Mark it for installation and click on green right arrow at top.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Strawberry Perl, Win32-GuiTest-1.60

```
perl Makefile.PL
dmake
dmake install
```

Then the module is up.